# Can I say to mongoose that I don’t need response?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I made a log system that sends the log to  MongoDB

‘LogModel.create(some log).’

I want to optimise more.

MongoDB may reply to the server whether save is successful or not which I do not ‘await.

Is there any interface that I can notice that I don't need a result?

Comment: Just don't await

Comment: @Alex Blex
Yeah but it let promise run in background ?